# iOS AIR app not getting user input after closing barcode reader ANE

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air, air-native-extension

I have a simple AIR app for iOS which has a text field along with a scan button.
On pressing the Scan button the app launches an ANE based on the pdf417.mobi SDK which uses the iPad camera to decode PDF417 barcodes.
The ANE works all fine and returns any scans back to AIR.

On closing, it closes the camera and returns back to AIR but I can't interact with the AIR app at all. No touches recognized whatsoever.

I've added an ENTER_FRAME event to trace continuously just so I can check if the app is still alive after closing the ANE and it keeps on tracing. It's just the user input that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about pdf417.mobi SDK but you don't have to use a specific SDK like theirs to scan pdf417 at all.

the Zxing library on Android supports that: https://github.com/zxing/zxing
and iOS also supports that natively: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2325/_index.html

For Adobe Air, To support pdf417 plus other formats, you may use this ANE of ours https://github.com/myflashlab/barcode-ANE

and here's how you should initialize it and set it to read pdf417 just for your reference:

```
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.barcode.Barcode;
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.barcode.BarcodeEvent;

var _ex:Barcode = new Barcode();
_ex.addEventListener(BarcodeEvent.RESULT, onResult);
_ex.addEventListener(BarcodeEvent.CANCEL, onCancel);

if (_ex.isSupported())
{
    trace("Please wait...");

    // to read only the selected barcode types. use an array to read one or more barcodes
    _ex.open([Barcode.PDF417], File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("com_doitflash_barcode_beep.mp3"), true, "Cancel");
}
else
{
    trace("isSupported: ", _ex.isSupported());
}

function onCancel(e:BarcodeEvent):void
{
    trace("scan canceled")
}

function onResult(e:BarcodeEvent):void
{
    trace("type is: ", e.param.type)
    trace("data is: ", e.param.data);
}
```